# Beamer frame key for wide frame

Tags: beamer

I'd like to create a `wide` key for beamer frame that would reduce the horizontal margins of the current frame, like

```latex
\begin{frame}[wide]
   \lipsum[2-4]
\end{frame}
```

I know there are questions and answers about using `minipage` or similar stuff to have wide frames, but I don't know how to combine them with the `wide` key.

Here is what I have for now that does not work

```latex
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  papersize={16.9335cm, 9.525cm},
  margin=0in
}
\newlength\hmargin
\setlength{\hmargin}{0.98in}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=\hmargin, text margin right=\hmargin}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{wide}[false]{%
  \setlength{\beamer@leftmargin}{0.45in}
  \setlength{\beamer@rightmargin}{0.30in}
}
\AtEndEnvironment{beamer@frameslide}{%
  \setlength{\beamer@leftmargin}{\hmargin}
  \setlength{\beamer@rightmargin}{\hmargin}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[wide]
 \lipsum[2-3]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I use this in my beamer: `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}`

Comment: @Mafsi Thanks, I know that option but I'm trying to convert a PPT template to a Beamer one and it's easier for item positioning to have specific height and width (for me).